# React redux not updating component when adding to array

Tags: reactjs, redux

So no matter what I do I can't get the component to refresh when I add a item to an array in the redux store.

What I use in my reducer to add to the redux state:

```
case ADD_NOTE_META:
  return [
    ...state,
    action.note,
  ];
```

The connector:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import NoteSection from './NoteSection.component';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
   notes: state.NotesMeta,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = () => ({});

export default connect(
   mapStateToProps,
   mapDispatchToProps,
)(NoteSection);
```

The component:

```
import React from 'react';

import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import NoteSelectorContainer from './noteselector/NoteSelector.connector';
import DeleteConfirmationMessage from './deletenoteconfirmationmessage/DeleteConfirmationMessage.connector';

function NoteSection(props) {
  const { notes } = props;

  return (
    <div id="divSelectNoteContainer">
      {notes.map(item => (
        <NoteSelectorContainer
          note={item}
          key={item.id}
        />
      ))}
      <DeleteConfirmationMessage />
    </div>
  );
}

NoteSection.defaultProps = {
  notes: [],
};

NoteSection.propTypes = {
  notes: PropTypes.array,
};

export default NoteSection;
```

The state in redux is structured like:

```
{
NotesMeta: [
    {
      id: '5b6cd6c49a46d',
      title: 'folder note',
      tags: [
        'test'
      ],
      parentid: '5b6cd6c49a48d'
    },
    {
      id: '5b6cd6c496ad2',
      title: 'test note',
      tags: [],
      parentid: null
    },
]
}
```

Output of console.log(notes) before add new note is run:

```
0: {id: "5b6cd6c49a46d", title: "folder note", tags: Array(1), parentid: "5b6cd6c49a48d"}
1: {id: "5b6cd6c496ad2", title: "test note", tags: Array(0), parentid: null}
```

After:

```
0: {id: "5b6cd6c49a46d", title: "folder note", tags: Array(1), parentid: "5b6cd6c49a48d"}
1: {id: "5b6cd6c496ad2", title: "test note", tags: Array(0), parentid: null}
2: {id: "5bb48aaae94c1", title: "New Note Title", tags: Array(0)}
```

I can see that the new note is added in both the redux store and the Notesection props however a new NoteSelectorContainer is never created.

Comment: how does your state look like  ?

Comment: @aravind_reddy I added the redux state to my post if thats the state you were talking about.

Comment: Are you sure, that you are using the connected NoteContainer instead of the NoteContainer component

Comment: @DeathorGlory9 i have added an answer see if that works for you

Comment: Could you `console.log(notes)` in the NotesSection component? It should get called every time the action fires with new data.

Comment: @Sebabouche added to the post.

Comment: Everything seems to work correctly and your component should update 

Comment: From what you showed us, I don't see anything bad. Could it be that a parent component prevents rerendering? Maybe try to search for an evil `shouldComponentUpdate`.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri It cant be, I removed all the other components that don't do anything and all the parent components are dumb components.